# Unable to find the file extension from Firebird blob sub_type 0 field

Tags: python, firebird

I have been working on data migration from a Firebird database to MongoDB using Python.

We able to extract the data and transformed to MongoDB successfully.

As a final stage, I am struck with finding the file extension for one field data ( `type = blob sub_type 0` ). I spent more than a week to figure out the data. But I'm not able to convert or decode data format. I have also tried online tool to convert binary to image. As per the table the binary data is an image file.

Same blob `sub_type 0` field for another table able to save as and able to open the file.

Please help me to figure out the data below

Below is the binary data (edited from flame robin tool) which can not able to read/view

```
21485A4CDB630000 8B64C56CC6673ADD 2EADFE1636DEE5EB 51801B2DB3D9CFB3 
1F8EAE8D015C0032 14C0591CA54D1ACA 14F2D93A2C954662 8E82565E5C7C8CCE 
6B3D83312F9D8935 F8D
```

all files binary data will be started with **21485A4C**

Comment: "The Unix utility program **file** can read and interpret magic numbers from files, and the file which is used to parse the information is called magic. The Windows utility **TrID** has a similar purpose."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 2):

A `blob sub_type binary` (`sub_type binary` is the human readable alias for `sub_type 0`) is just that, binary data. Firebird doesn't know nor care what you put in there. There is no filename or file extension in there unless you put it in there (or put it in an accompanying column). And given you haven't shown us how the data was put in there, we have no way to know if it is there or how to get it out.

If on the other hand you want to infer the image type based on the data, your question can then be reduced to *"I have some binary data. I know it is an image, but I don't know its type. How can I determine the image type from (anonymous) binary data?"*. Your problem then is no longer one related to Firebird.

Decoding `21485A4C` to ASCII gives you `!HZL` (reversed `LZH!`) which might an indication it is LZH or maybe LHA compressed.

I don't think that will help you find out the image type. In other words, you will need to get back to the source and find out what data was put in and how it was encoded to be able to know how to correctly decode it.

I would assume that you have access to the program that originally created the data, so I would start looking there.